# Architecture for modular Spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, architecture

I want create skeleton for big ecommerce project. It will be huge project. It should be  a core module and set of additional modules.
Now I am thinking about maven modules into Spring MVC project. But I am newbie in maven and Spring
How make each module independent from other modules? Any best practice?
Any examples or code snippets?

Comment: Read this: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: Thanks! Good book. I will use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a multi-module Maven project which was created couple of months back.
I can give you some pointers.

It can be structured as a parent project and multiple child modules under it.
In my case the output generated with Maven is a .war file and which contains jar files from each child module.

From maven you can build each modules separately if you want.

This is a useful link for multi-module creation
http://skillshared.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-create-multi-module-project-with.html

These are the layers on a high level:

Bean > Service > DAO [JPA]

Another useful link on directory structure is 
[Maven Multi Module Project Structuring Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690215/maven-multi-module-project-structuring-issues)

Comment: i know it's not for here but i have same project know and I have problem to load spring .xml file. one of my modules is an web application (web service actually and using jersey to build it). requests come and web application call other modules to (spring is used in other modules). now it can't find the .xml file and throw IOException, please help me if know any helpful links or guidance